# Автоматическое преобразование чисел из object в long в Web API контроллере

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

Я пытаюсь реализовать Web API контроллер, который принимает из Json коллекцию в формате словаря:

```c#
[HttpPost]
public string Save([FromBody]Dictionary<string, object> keyValuePairs)
```

Передаваемый Json имеет примерно следующий вид (иными словами это набор формата "ключ - значение", причем перечень значений и типы данных не определены заранее):

```
{
    "str": "Name",
    "ID": 0,
    "visible": false,
    "userID": 66,
    ...
}
```

Моя проблема заключается в том, что даже небольшие числа (0, 66 из примера выше) в итоге конвертируются в тип **`long`**, а не **`int`**, что в моем случае недопустимо, так как конфликтует с существующими решениями. Определять необходимость конвертации данных в контроллере или реализовать дополнительный класс я не могу.

[image: получаемый тип]

1. Почему я получаю именно тип **`long`** и можно ли это изменить, редактируя только вид аргументов контроллера?
2. Есть ли способы получать содержимое Json иначе?
3. Возможно ли указывать формат данных в Json (в самом POST-запросе)?

Comment: Чтобы изменить способ, как парсятся аргументы, вам надо будет менять настройки сериализатора.

Comment: @tym32167, не могли бы вы объяснить где эти параметры можно изменить? Где они вообще задаются?

Comment: вам надо для всех чисел, что парсятся этим прилодением, вместо long иметь int, верно?

Comment: @tym32167 не для всех. Иногда возможно наличие действительного long, который не нуждается в конвертации типа.

Comment: тогда вам наверное будкт проще просто тут, в действии контроллера, перегнать входящий словарик в новый, по дороге конвертируя long->int, чем настраивать парсер для одного то метода одного контроллера.

Comment: Есть варианты: [How do I change the default Type for Numeric deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9444519/2881286) //cc @tym32167